# Mono TextTransform.exe can't find referenced assemblies

Tags: mono, t4

I'm trying to use Mono's TextTransform.exe to run T4 templates written for a Windows environment on Linux.

We've got a custom assembly, providing some utility functions used in the template, which builds in MonoDevelop.  I'm running TextTransform.exe like this:

```
/usr/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.TextTemplating/TextTransform.exe \
    -I=./IncludeScripts/ \
    -P=./DataModelDefinition/Output/x86/Release/ \
    -a='dataModelPath!./DataModel/DataModel.xml' \
    -out=generation.log \
    Templates/Process.tt
(0,0): ERROR Metadata file `DataModelDefinition.dll' could not be found
```

The folder ./DataModelDefinition/Output/x86/Release/ does contain DataModelDefinition.dll, which builds without warning or error.  I've tried adding an explicit reference to the assembly on the command-line with `-r=./DataModelDefinition/Output/x86/Release/DataModelDefinition.dll` but it makes no difference.

Is there something I'm missing here?

**Edit:** Also tried `export MONO_PATH=$(pwd)/DataModelDefinition/Output/x86/Release/` but it makes no difference.

Comment: Have you added "mono -r=./DataModelDefinition/Output/x86/Release/DataModelDefinition.dll " in front of the TransForm.exe or did you add the argument to TransForm.exe ?

Comment: What you have suggested above gives `Unknown command line option: '-r=...'`.  Adding the `-r=...` after TextTransform.exe makes no difference.

Comment: Well, yeah, it was an option for gmcs, not mono. Just copy that dll into that directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in TextTransform and has been fixed in the current HEAD on github.